# Can a contract on Hedera Hashgraph be written to allow the contract owner to pay gas fees for Token Association?

Tags: hedera-hashgraph

I am working on a project where I'd like to create a smart contract on the Hedera Hashgraph network and do stuff with associations. I have a specific requirement that I'm not sure is possible, and I would appreciate your guidance on this.

My goal is to create a contract where the contract owner can pay the gas fees for Token Association transactions. This way, users associating with the token wouldn't need to worry about having HBAR in their accounts to cover the gas fees.

Is this possible on the Hedera Hashgraph network? If so, could you provide some high-level guidance or examples of how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible for a smart contract or an account to pay token association fee for another account at the moment. But if you would like that feature, you can create a Hedera Improvement Proposal. https://hips.hedera.com/all.html